# How can I test what my `__main__` file does?

Tags: python, testing, module, pytest

I'm using pytest. NB W10.
I will be running my app by going `> python src/core`. "core" is my central module, with a `__main__.py` file.

For that reason I'm putting my "tests" directory in [project root]/src/core.

I have a test file test_xxx.py. In it I try to import `__main__`:

```
import __main__

... 

def test_xxxxx():
   print(f'main {__main__} type {type(__main__)}')
```

This prints the following:

```
main <module '__main__' from 'D:\\apps\\Python\\virtual_envs\\doc_indexer v2.0.0\\Scripts\\pytest.exe\\__main__.py'> type <class 'module'>
```

... in other words, it is importing not my local `__main__.py` from my local "core" module, but pytest's own `__main__` from its module. So far so understandable. Then I look at sys.path:

```
path: D:\My Documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\doc_indexer\src\core\tests
path: D:\My Documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\doc_indexer\src\core
path: D:\apps\Python\virtual_envs\doc_indexer v2.0.0\Scripts\pytest.exe
path: D:\apps\Python\PyQt5
...
```

Now I'm scratching my head, not for the first time with pytest. This ...src\core path is listed ***before*** ...Scripts\pytest.exe. Why would pytest identify its own `__main__.py` and import it, before importing `__main__.py` from a path which precedes it?

I've also tried various experiments with `importlib`. Nothing seems to work.

So generally, is there any way to actually import that file ...src/core/`__main__py`?

I realise that this file should do minimal things before handing on to another file, but for completeness I'd just like to test that `main()` does in fact do that. Is there any way to run `__main__.main()` in a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Python program creates a module named `__main__` on startup, based on the script being executed.

As a result, `import __main__` *always* finds a module by that name, meaning it does not need to define one from, say, a file named `__main__.py`. In your case, you executed `pytest` (which is primarily a simple wrapper around `import pytest; pytest.console_main()`. (The script `pytest`, stored in a directory on your search path, is separate from a module defined by `pytest.py` in your Python library.)

One solution would be to make sure you can import `__main__.py` using another package, so that `somepackage.__main__` is distinct from `__main__`.

However, `__main__.py` is never intended to be imported as a module. It's the file that defines a script when you try to execute a directory or an archive file as a script. If it contains code that needs to be tested, I would recommend factoring that into a separate module with `__main__.py` itself imports.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the mechanism here and also the thinking behind not testing that actual file. Maybe it'd be simpler to start the app by going `python src/core/start.py`: I see that `__name__` is still "`__main__`" if you do that, so nice and generic. Also I've put in a "FATAL ..." message in `__main__.py` saying how to start the app.